ARM64. Calling memset() on the address returned by mmap() PCIe BAR causes a BUS error
I wrote a very simple test program in the application layer. First, I open the PCIe device, then mmap() the starting space of the PCIe BAR. Finally, I use the address returned by mmap(), apply an offset, and pass it to memset() for zeroing. I found that regardless of how the address is aligned, the maximum size passed to memset is only 240 bytes. When the address alignment is less than 16 bytes, the maximum size passed to memset() is reduced to less than 8 bytes. I don't know why this is happening.
There are no AER errors when the bus error occurs.
Using memset_io()/memcpy_toio() in the driver does not cause errors, regardless of the size, but these require specific I/O interfaces. I am unsure what happens after using memset() in user space because it does not use the specific I/O interfaces.
// driver
static int pci_rc_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    resource_size_t offset = vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;
    resource_size_t start = 0;
    
    start = bar2_start_addr;  // bar2_start_addr = pci_resource_start(pdev, BAR_2); bar2_start_addr = 0x1B70000
    
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
    
    return io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, ((start + offset) >> PAGE_SHIFT), vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot);
}

// user
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    void *bar = NULL;

    fd = open("/dev/pcie-dev", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    
    bar = mmap(0, 65536, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    
    memset(bar, 0, 241); // Bus error

    munmap(bar, 65536);
    
    close(fd); 
    
    return 0;   
}


Is it Intel CPU? But in any case what you describing looks like cache line related. In any case look at how other drivers do similar.

@0andriy Thank you for your response. You mentioned something related to the cache. In my mmap implementation, there is a line of code:
vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot); 
This means bypassing the cache, right? This is not an Intel CPU.

Does your driver enable the PCI device (rc = pci_enable_device(pcidev);)? (Note: normally this would be done in the driver's PCI probe function, and it would be disabled again with pci_disable_device(pcidev); in the PCI remove function.)

@Ian Abbott Thank you for your feedback. I have indeed implemented the pci_enable_device(pcidev); in the probe function and pci_disable_device(pcidev); in the remove function as you suggested.
